# I am loosing fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

i am trying to create a system to send multiple emails with attachment. But it is only the first email that has the picture attached, the rest is empty. What am i doing wrong?

As you can see, i have tried different(and more).

```
 protected void BtnSenMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string filename=null;
    string tema = TxtEmnefelt.Text;
    string indhold = TxtIndhold.Text;

    string fileExtencion = null;
    int fileSize = 0;
    string FileNameToAdd = null;
    fileSize = FiUpLoad.FileBytes.Length;
    emailList = (List<string>)Session["EmailList"];

if (FiUpLoad.HasFile)
        {
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = FiUpLoad.PostedFile;
            filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            fileExtencion = Path.GetExtension(filename);

            try
            {
                if (fileSize > 0)
                {
                    if (fileExtencion.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtencion.ToLower() == ".bmp" || fileExtencion.ToLower() == ".gif" || fileExtencion.ToLower() == ".png" || fileExtencion.ToLower() == ".pdf")
                    {
                        //Session["imgUpload"] = Path.GetFileName(FiUpLoad.PostedFile.FileName);
                        Session["imgUpload"] = FiUpLoad.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
                        FileNameToAdd = Path.GetFileName(FiUpLoad.PostedFile.FileName);
                        // FileName = Session["imgUpload"];
                        //mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FiUpLoad.PostedFile.InputStream,FileName ));
                        //mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FiUpLoad.PostedFile.InputStream, Convert.ToString(Session["imgUpload"])));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LblError.Text = "Kun jpg,png,gif.bmp og pdf filer kan vedhæftes!";
                        LblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

 foreach (var item in emailList)
        {
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("xxxxxxxxxxx", item);
            mm.Subject = tema;
            mm.Body = indhold;
            //mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FiUpLoad.PostedFile.InputStream, Convert.ToString(Session["imgUpload"])));
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FiUpLoad.PostedFile.InputStream, FileNameToAdd));
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtpClient.Send(mm);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may need to seek your InputStream back to the beginning after each Email sent. Something like this:  `FiUpLoad.PostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);`.  Just a guess, though.

Comment: I agree the problem is probably that the stream is at the end. Not sure if OP will be able to seek to the beginning in this context. In worse case, he could read it once, and recreate a memory stream from the result of the first read.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your InputStream is already read after the first iteration of your loop. Subsequent attempts to create attachment from it will try to read the same stream, but the "current position" of the stream is already at the end, so they read nothing more.

You could try, for instance :

- Reset the stream read cursor by `seek`ing to the beginning. I am not sure if you can do it in this context, though.

OR

- Read the whole InputStream *before* the `for` loop into a byte array, (if file not too big)
- Then create a new MemoryStream from the array, then reset it with `seek`  *at the beginning of* each iteration of your loop, and pass this stream to `Attachment.Add`

OR

(if Add attachment for some reason closes the stream)

- Recreate a new MemoryStream at each iteration of your loop, with the array result of previous proposition

There are probably more efficient ways, but I hope you get the idea.